# Using a jQuery script to play video and pause and set time to 0, I get: this.currentTime = 0; Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR

Tags: jquery, video

I have several divs that hold video objects. They play on the click of a thumbnail. But I was having a problem with the videos continuing to play 'behind the scenes' if a user click another choice. So, I got this from a fellow Overflower to 'stop' the video, return it to the first frame, fade it out, and then fade in and play the next chosen video:

Here's the jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
$('div.video').hide();

$('.icon').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id'),
        thisDiv=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']"),
        thisVideo=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']").find('video');

    $('video').each(function () {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    });

       $('div.video').not(thisDiv).fadeOut();

       thisDiv.fadeIn();      
       thisVideo.get(0).play();   
});
});
```

And the html of one of the eight divs for the video object:

```
<div class="video" data-id="1" >
<video width="auto" height="100%" controls="controls">
  <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="videos/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
<object data="videos/video.mp4" width="auto" height="100%">
  <embed src="videos/video.swf" width="auto" height="100%" />
</object> 
</video>
</div>
```

And it works... Most of the time. Sometimes, I get the error:

```
this.currentTime = 0; Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

In Chrome's error log. IE8 displays the same error.

Does anyone know what this is all about? And what I can do to fix it?

Comment: This error means your video is not loaded, so there's no currentTime.